# SQLite3 imported information not working in a while loop

Tags: python, database, while-loop, sqlite

```
vrnaam = input("Vul de voornaam van de student in: ")
atnaam = input("Vul de achternaam van de student in: ")
while vrnaam or atnaam not in str(stdpaden):
    print("Foute invoer")
    vrnaam = input("Vul de voornaam van de student in: ")
    atnaam = input("Vul de achternaam van de student in: ")
```

The `while loop` is for if someone puts in the name and surname of someone incorrectly. "stdpaden" is extracted from a table inside an SQLite 3 database. Using a print statement it looks like this:

```
[('4', 'Joswa', 'Schrevel', '1', 'Intelligent Systems', 'nee')]
```

Yet when I call `vrnaam = Joswa` and `atnaam = Schrevel`, it doesn't work and it just stays inside the loop. Is there anything I am overseeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `stdpaden` is a list of tuples, so you need to flatten that to a list of strings. You can do that in a list comprehension (`[i for x in stdpaden for i in x]`). Then, your `or` statement doesn't make sense as is: I guess you're trying to see if both `vrnaam` or `atnaam`, so you need to give each their own `not in` statement. I think this works (it breaks out of the loop if you insert `Joswa` and `Schrevel`):

```
while vrnaam not in [i for x in stdpaden for i in x] or atnaam not in [i for x in stdpaden for i in x]:
    print("Foute invoer")
    vrnaam = input("Vul de voornaam van de student in: ")
    atnaam = input("Vul de achternaam van de student in: ")
```

For clarity of code, I would personally unpack your list of tuples first:

```
stdpaden = [i for x in stdpaden for i in x]

while vrnaam not in stdpaden or atnaam not in stdpaden:
    print("Foute invoer")
    vrnaam = input("Vul de voornaam van de student in: ")
    atnaam = input("Vul de achternaam van de student in: ")
```

**Alternative to the list comprehension**

Instead of `[i for x in stdpaden for i in x]`, you could use `itertools` to flatten your `stdpaden` list of tuples:

```
stdpaden = list(itertools.chain(*stdpaden))

while vrnaam not in stdpaden or atnaam not in stdpaden:
    print("Foute invoer")
    vrnaam = input("Vul de voornaam van de student in: ")
    atnaam = input("Vul de achternaam van de student in: ")
```